# How to include buttons in SharePoint list view?

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-view

I have a list in which I want to easily and quickly get an entry time and an exit time, so the best solution would be to have, for each item already created, two buttons.

When clicking on it, it saves the entry time and the exit time in the required fields.

I guess JavaScript could do that, but how? Has anybody faced a similar problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To update my post, i found what i needed in JsLink CSR & CSS so if anybody have the same need : do think of that solution.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could also post the code you used, the steps you followed and so on. The answer is not really helpful right now